# How to use StaggeredGridView and ActionBarSherlock combined

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I have implemented sliding menu with action bar using "ActionBar Sherlock and Sliding menu" libraries.Now i tried to use staggeredGridView.  But i am getting error as "JAR MISMATCH present in StaggeredGridView-Android Support v4 library"

How can i use staggeredGridView along with actionBar sherlock?

Comment: you need to remove the duplicate jar from any of your project, or use the same jar for your project and StaggeredGridView lib

Comment: yes ., but the error is pointing to the android support v4 library present in the StaggeredGridView ., how can i remove that,if i removed that library,i am getting errors in that StaggerdGridView.

Comment: replace it with the one you have in ABS or in SlidingMenu

Comment: if i replace it with ABS means it gives error for
"
import android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.VelocityTrackerCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.EdgeEffectCompat;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both ABS and StaggeredGridView come with the compatibility library, but probably with different versions of the JAR. You should replace one of the compatibility JAR's with the other, the Android SDK will ignore duplicate JAR's as long as they are exact matches.

As to which JAR you should copy, always copy the newest version (probably ABS version), alternatively you can grab the latest version from the SDK and overwrite them both.

Hope this helps..